# React-Dc-Js: How to access the selected values of select-menu?

Tags: reactjs, dc.js

In the code given below when I click on the options in the select menu, I want to store the selected value, how can I do this?

I want this so that I can pass the same to url search params.

Please find the sample code with a select menu using react-dc-js here:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-dc-js-forked-flvwgk?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx